# xampp is showing my default gateway instead of showing visitor ip

Tags: php, xampp, ip

I have a xampp server installed in a windows cpu which I use as a public server for my clients. Now I have made a request box for my clients to drop some request on it, and I am saving their IP in db while sending data through php. I use this php script to get the clients IP address

```
function get_ip() {

    //Just get the headers if we can or else use the SERVER global
    if ( function_exists( 'apache_request_headers' ) ) {

        $headers = apache_request_headers();

    } else {

        $headers = $_SERVER;

    }

    //Get the forwarded IP if it exists
    if ( array_key_exists( 'X-Forwarded-For', $headers ) && filter_var( $headers['X-Forwarded-For'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 ) ) {

        $the_ip = $headers['X-Forwarded-For'];

    } elseif ( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $headers ) && filter_var( $headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 )
    ) {

        $the_ip = $headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    } else {

        $the_ip = filter_var( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 );

    }

    return $the_ip;

}

echo get_ip();
```

But XAMPP is showing the machine's default gateway instead of showing the visitor's IP.

How can I fix that?

Comment: basic debuggin: put some echo/output into each of your if() tests to track down WHICH code path was taken. Plus, WHICH "the machine"? Your xamp box? The client box?

Comment: if your machine is behind a NAT, then all the IP will be masked as the gateway ip of your server.

Comment: It's showing the cpu's default gateway in which cpu the xampp is installed.

I have tested the xampp server from several connection and also the proxy, but still that showing the machine's default gateway in which machine the xampp is installed on.

Comment: Okay I have just allowed port 80 tcp in firewall, but it's still showing the default gateway instead of showing the visitors ip.  !!!